# PHP / XML output does not show any content in client browser

Tags: php, json, xml

I have the following PHP code:

process.php script for XML output format

```
<?php
$name='Imran';
$nick='Alkan';
header('Content-type: text/xml charset=utf-8');
?>
<echo1>
    <name><?php echo $name; ?></name>
    <nick><?php echo $nick; ?></nick>
</echo1>
```

and index.php for showing values of name and nick tags

```
<?php
$xml=file_get_contents('process.php');
$xml=simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo $xml->name.' '.$xml->nick;
?>
```

Comment: _"I uploaded this process.php script on `http://mey3ss.gq/test/index.php`"_ - that automatically redirects me to `http://mey3ss.gq/test/index.php?i=1`, and _that_ URL appears to just show the original XML document, including the `echo1` element ...?

Comment: `file_get_contents('process.php')` - this will read the actual _content_ of the file, it will not execute any PHP code contained in there. And SimpleXML will treat everything inside `<?...?>` as a processing instruction, so your `name` and `nick` elements do not actually habe any content.

Comment: Thanks. So, how can I execute this PHP code to use its generated tags (tags: name and nick) to show values? because, you said: file_get_contents() read contents of file only ...

Answer (score 1):

it does show output: a single whitespace.

in

```
    <name><?php echo $name; ?></name>
```

the `<?...?>` is interpreted as a xml comment, and thus the `<name>` has no text content (it contains a xml comment, but not any text) thus `(string)$xml->name` is emptystring. it's the same with `(string)$xml->nick`,  so your `echo $xml->name.' '.$xml->nick;`  boils down to `echo ((string)$xml->name).' '.((string)$xml->nick);` which boils down to just `echo ' ';`  , thus in your browser a single whitespace is printed :)

the problem here is that `file_get_contents()` does not do what you think it does, it does not actually execute the contents of the file as php.. i think you're looking for require(), try

```
$xml=require('process.php');
```

which does practically what you incorrectly believed file_get_contents does, eg

```
$xml=eval(file_get_contents('process.php'));
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I test the code using require(). but I got this error 'XML Parsing Error: junk after document element Location: localhost/test/xml Line Number 4, Column 9:'. I added <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> too, but nothing get changed

Comment: @Alkan probably because it's no longer a valid XML file. try ```<?php
$name='Imran';
$nick='Alkan';
header('Content-type: text/xml charset=utf-8');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
?>``` so the output starts with a valid "XML declaration line"

Comment: Thanks again. I tested it but not working

Comment: neat, Alvaro figured it out: ob_start();require('process.php');$xml=ob_get_clean();

Comment: Not working yet. for process.php i use: <?php
$name='Imran';
$nick='Alkan';
header('Content-type: text/xml charset=utf-8');
?>
<echo1>
 <name><?php echo $name; ?></name>
    <nick><?php echo $nick; ?></nick>
</echo1> .... and for index.php i use: <?php
ob_start();
require_once('process.php');
$xml=ob_get_clean();
$xml=simplexml_load_string($xml) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo $xml->name.' '.$xml->nick;
?> . but it's not working yet. I thought json output is better, i did it, but for json, a NULL string is displayed only

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, `file_get_contents()` does not execute scripts, it only opens files.

The most straightforward way to run simple PHP code is `require`. However, since your code prints to standard output you also need to capture that:

```
ob_start();
require 'process.php';
$xml = ob_end_clean();
```

Beware that the script also generates HTTP headers, so you need to do this before you generate any output.

Said that, this is the most inconvenient design. Why don't you just put your code in a regular function?

Comment: I found it. for file_get_contents() only a full url is needed in my problem. for example, file_get_contents('process.php'); only returns a NULL value. but file_get_contents('http://localhost/project/json/process.php'); return my json contents and it's ready for decoding by json_decode(). Thanks for your help, friends

Comment: Why trigger a network request to execute local code? This design looks more a goal on itself than something really needed.